# NFSoRDMA support using MLNX_OFED and Linux Kernel 4.4

Tags: linux, nfs, infiniband

We are trying to use the latest MLNX_OFED v4 with SLES12 SP3 and Kernel version 4.4.73-5. The MLNX OFED v4 package does not support RDMA (for some reason this was dropped). We tried to download the source package and build it. The installer script checks for Kernel version 4.15 and for all other versions disables nfsrdma and mlnx-nfsrdma.

1. Any idea why this change in the MLNX OFED v4 packages?
2. How to enable support for NFS over RDMA using above combination and EDR?